# How to set the right margin of a chart through a pine script?

Tags: pine-script

How can I set the Right Margin of a chart through a pine script?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that through pinescript.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31931441)

Comment: The answer is he cannot do what he asks if he can do. I don't see how my answer does not answer his question. How am I supposed to answer if the answer is "no"?

Comment: The point is that your answer does not solve his problem. If you can suggest a workaround that is able to make out what he needs, I'd upvote your answer too. @vitruvius

Comment: @lemon Telling someone that something is not possible is still an answer. If you think it is a bad answer, you should downvote.

Comment: An answer should solve a problem. If there's no solution to the problem, there should be no answer, only comments, though I agree that this is just my point of view. I'll leave to the author of the question to judge on this answer. @MarkRotteveel

Comment: @lemon The discussion on this meta-question might be helpful: [Is "this is not possible" an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer). Though the top-voted answer suggests you need to be able to demonstrate (but proving a negative is pretty hard to do).